# firebase update promise result

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I have an angular factory and a controller in the format below. I am calling register free courses function which updates the firebase database. However in the firebase manual it says update() can return a Promise you can use to know when the write is committed to the database.
In my case there can be possibility that the update will not be committed however I want to catch it. I am trying this code but its now working.

```
.controller(...){
CourseFact.RegisterFreeCourses(...).then(function(value){
                  ...success
                }).catch(function (e) {
                   ...fail
                           });
                   })
                   }
    .factory('CourseFact'...
    {
          return {
                RegisterFreeCourses:{
                    updates[.../...] = postDataPlayer;

                    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
                 }
            }
    }
```

how can I fix it or is there a better example ?

Comment: Maybe try instead of catch another anonymous function so:
then(success,error);
function success(response){}
function error(response){}

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? also please show the calling code...

Comment: @vodich thanks it worked

Comment: Thanks I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

error response is already in promise chain so you don't have to catch it. You can just specify success and error function and they will get called once the promise is resolved/rejected

```
.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
function successCallback(response){
    //do something
 }
function errorCallback(error){
    //do something else
}
```